# How do I fix the "Packet mismatch -92141241 11 214124" error in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I fix the "Packet mismatch -92141241 11 214124" error .
I'm going to answer my own question, because the phrase packet size mismatch comes up regularly in posts relating to ffmpeg, but I've nowhere seen a satisfactory solution to it.
My command is :

```
ffmpeg -rw_timeout 1000000 -i rtmp://ip/appName/StreamName -vn -ar 16000 -ac 1 -f segment -segment_format wav -segment_time 3 %d.wav
```

The error is :

```
[segment e X5b4a87e55e0 Upening I.wav for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53e0] Opening '2.wav' for writing
[segment @ 8x5634a87e53e0] Opening '3.wav' for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53e0] Opening '4.wav' for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53e0] Opening '5.wav' for writing
[segment @ 8x5634a87e53e0] Opening '6.wav' for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53e0] Opening '7.wav' for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53eØ] Opening '8.wav' for writing
[segnent @ 0x5634a87e53e0] Opening '9.wav' for writing
[segnent @ 0x5634a87e53e0J Opening '10.wav' for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53eØJ Opening '11.wav' for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53eØ] Opening '12.wav' for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53eØ] Opening '13.wav' for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53eØ] Opening '14.wav' for writing
[segment @ 0x5634a87e53e0] Opening '15.wav' for writing
[segment @ Øx5634a87e53e0] Opening '16.wav' for writing
[segment @ 0x5634a87e53e0] Opening '17.wav' for writing
[flv @ 0x5634a87df740J Packet mismatch -92244280 11 167729
[flv @ 0x5634a87df740] Packet mismatch -594165790 48656 216385
[flv @ ex5634a87df740] Packet mismatch -289696512 49936 2663212
[flv @ 0x5634a87df740] Packet mismatch -606269659 56848 323169
[flv @ 0x5634a87df740] Packet mismatch -1989457532 419680 372849
[flv @ 0x5634a87df740] Packet mismatch -1243998453 49937 422786
```

How do I fix ?

Thanks!

Comment: This refers to corrupt packets in the input - nothing to fix.

Comment: But if I pull the flv file directly, this error will not occur.
Command is 'ffmpeg -i rtmp://ip/AppName/StreamName -c copy  1.flv'
@Gyan